# Mapping a dictionary key and its corresponding values from a list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I've managed to read in a .txt file and read in each line as a different element of a list; pretty easy. Next I stripped all the non-numerical characters from each element (leaving just 0-9 and '.'), also pretty easily done.

However, then I'm left with a list with 90 total elements. Starting from element 0, I want every 5th element to be the key to my dictionary (0, 5, 10, 15, etc). Then I want the 4 value in between to correspond to the values of the previous key (as a list length 4).

For example: 
my_list[0] is the key with corresponding values my_list[1:5]
my_list[5] is the key with corresponding values my_list[6:10]
etc, etc

I've managed to take every 5th element out and make it it's own list; just holding the keys. And I've even managed to create another list which holds all the in between values as seperate lists of length 4.

I've tried:

```
my_dict = dict()

for i in my_keys:
    my_dict[i] = [x for x in every_four]
```

AND

```
my_dict = dict()

for i in my_keys:
    for x in every_four:
        my_dict[i] = x
```

The first one gives me the correct keys but each value is just a the whole every_four list, not just every element. The second one gives me the correct keys but each value is just the first element of the every_four list, it's not iterating through.

Can someone help me get it working this way? And is there any easier way I can do this from the original array? Just set every 5th element to a key and the four elements in between as the corresponding values for that key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want every fifth element as key of your dictionary and list of next consecutive four elements as values, then you can try dictionary comprehension.

```
my_dict = {my_list[i] : my_list[i+1 : i+5] for i in range(0, len(my_list), 5)}
```

For sample input -

```
my_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

output will be -

```
{0: [1, 2, 3, 4], 5: [6, 7, 8, 9]}
```

But this code will generate an empty list as value if for a key no next element is present.

Input -

```
my_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Output -

```
{0: [1, 2, 3, 4], 10: [], 5: [6, 7, 8, 9]}
```

As for your code, assuming you get `every_four` and `my_keys` correct, there are some problems. In your second attempt, you are looping over every element in the  `my_keys` list and adding that as key of the dictionary. And in the inner loop you are adding `x` as the value of the dictionary. So, for every iteration in your inner loop, the value for key `i` is getting overwritten.
What you could have done is -

```
my_dict = dict()

for i in my_keys:
    for x in every_four:
        my_dict.setdefault(i, []).append(x)
```

For first attempt, I really need to see how you get `my_keys` and `every_four` to point out the error.

Comment: LIFE SAVER! Thank you!

Comment: @Troy, glad it helped. If this answers your question, can you accept the answer?

Comment: Of course! Sorry, bit new to this whole thing. Just if you didn't mind, do you know why the for loops I was trying weren't working how I was expecting them to?

Comment: to do that i need to see how you get `every_four`

Comment: @Troy, I have updated my answer. Please see the explanation